# How to import data from CSV to MySQL

Tags: go

I have CSV x gb and want to insert into mysql, I would use Go for this, but I am not hitting the right way to do it, has anyone done that?

my proect: https://github.com/DevJoseWeb/AMCOM/tree/master/amcom-systems-go

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the language, there's two basic approaches. First is to read and parse the CSV file yourself and insert one row at a time. This is inefficient.

The other is to use MySQL's [`load data local infile`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to load a CSV file into a table letting MySQL do all the work. The `local` part means you'll be sending MySQL the CSV file.

Unlike other SQL statements, this requires special client support to read and send the CSV file. Fortunately the [`go-sql-driver` you're using has this support](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#load-data-local-infile-support) and notes a few caveats.

> Files must be whitelisted by registering them with mysql.RegisterLocalFile(filepath) (recommended) or the Whitelist check must be deactivated by using the DSN parameter allowAllFiles=true (Might be insecure!).
>
> To use a io.Reader a handler function must be registered with mysql.RegisterReaderHandler(name, handler) which returns a io.Reader or io.ReadCloser. The Reader is available with the filepath Reader:: then. Choose different names for different handlers and DeregisterReaderHandler when you don't need it anymore.
>
> See the godoc of Go-MySQL-Driver for details.

Go-MySQL-Driver has examples. With [`RegisterLocalFile`](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#RegisterLocalFile)...

```
filePath := "/home/gopher/data.csv"
mysql.RegisterLocalFile(filePath)
err := db.Exec("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + filePath + "' INTO TABLE foo")
if err != nil {
...
```

And with [`RegisterReaderHandler`](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#RegisterReaderHandler).

```
mysql.RegisterReaderHandler("data", func() io.Reader {
    var csvReader io.Reader // Some Reader that returns CSV data
    ... // Open Reader here
    return csvReader
})
err := db.Exec("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Reader::data' INTO TABLE foo")
if err != nil {
...
```

Comment: Lord you're a monster, it showed everything I wanted to see, thank you!

Comment: omg! mysql.RegisterReaderHandler saved from parsing remote files (HDFS) and load them to mysql!!